# Foley recording budget

Tags: foley

Hi everybody,

I'm an assistant producer organizing the future sound post production of a film and I'm considering various foley facilities. I'm wondering which you think is a usual budget for the foley of a 90 minute film (both in Europe and in the US), since I've been getting very dissimilar prices. This is a very "normal" independent film; no martial arts or robots or anything like that. A plain and simple drama needing good clean sounds and a full M&E track.

If anyone can help with this, I thank you in advance.

Paulo

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'usual' budget, but bear in mind the total budget of the film is a factor, as quoting foley for a us$500k indie film would be lot different than quoting foley on a us$10mill indie film, as the expectations an attention to detail would be very different...

Comment: Hi Paulo, I'm currently coordinating post on a 90min Irish drama feature & am also researching foley facilities at the moment. I'd love to hear how you got on & if you have found anywhere you could recommend? Thanks,
Susan.

Comment: Hi, Paulo
If you need a help with facility, please, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim mentioned in his comment, there really aren't "usual" prices. There are a number of factors that could be contributing to you being given dissimilar quotes: experience of the foley team (which will also affect how they view the scope of work), equipment and props that they have available, overhead costs (salaries/wages, rent, electricity, etc.), and the level of demand for their services.

If you have a supervising sound editor/sound designer/audio post-supervisor, bring them into the conversation. He or she will be able to help you assess which are the best alternatives, and can help you understand where and why the discrepancies in quotes are occurring.

Answer (score -5):

Hi Paulo

Well that's a tricky one but something I can help with

I'm a supervising sound editor within films and will be able to help with this

Get in touch to discuss your options

Thanks

Chris